# How to migrate database?

Tags: java, spring

I've no background with JAVA. I'm working on Angular project. So I have an assignment where they have provided me a .jar file and told me to run the server using java -jar payment.jar

This is a database configuration file.

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/payments-system
#Hibernate-Settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#Database Connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb 
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I'm using MYSQL. I don't what what DBMS this particular java project use. How to migrate the database? Well they have provided me the documentation for the API but Haven't included details about the systems  architecture.

Comment: You are not using MySQL, you are using [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html). Does the application support MySQL instead of H2?

Comment: how do i migrate it to H2?

Comment: Ask the vender of the application if it supports MySQL. We don't know.

Answer (score 0):

## H2 Database Engine

[*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) is a free-of-cost open-source relational SQL database system that you can easily include embedded within an app or run separately as a server.

H2 is a competitor to MySQL. I would choose H2 over MySQL personally.

If you know the app is built for H2, I would use H2 rather than try MySQL, unless you have some overriding reason to use MySQL. Unfortunately, SQL database systems are not anywhere near as easy to substitute despite the promises of the SQL standard.